# ORDS not like - is it possible?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

I'm trying to consume Oracle ORDS endpoint which works correct. The problem is when i try to add a query of type NOT LIKE
I'm receiving - bad request (400)

My URL looks like :

```
https://my.api.com/v1/results?q="type":{"$not like":"FP%"}}
```

encoded :

```
https://my.api.com/v1/results?q=%7B%22type%22%3A%7B%22%24notlike%22%3A%22FP%25%22%7D%7D
```

I've also tried with :

```
https://my.api.com/v1/results?q=%7B%22type%22%3A%7B%22%24not%20like%22%3A%22FP%25%22%7D%7D
```

but not of them works. If i use only **LIKE** , the API works as expected.
The question is if **NOT LIKE** is supported at all ? If not what workaround i could use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support a query parameter filter for a 'NOT LIKE' predicate. You can see the full list in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.4/aelig/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-6FDB9F47-EAB9-409B-9CB1-79D79B46AC28)

What we do have is $instr and $ninstr

[I have examples for using INSTR and LIKE here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2022/02/filtering-and-searching-strings-using-ords-query-parameters/)

So a GET on my activities list, with this query parameter filter added -

/?q={"activity_name":{"$ninstr":"run"}}

Brings me back activities that that don't have RUN, run, or Run in the name is said activity.

[image]